# System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'NPer' is not a valid value.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I was able to debug my coding then, when I click my "Calculate" button, the error message

> System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'NPer' is not a valid value.'

pops up (first pic). The second pic is my app. The reset button and the exit button work, but when I click the "Calculate" button it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

   Const dblMonths_Year As Double = 12
   Const dblNew_Rate As Double = 0.05
   Const dblUsed_Rate As Double = 0.08
   Dim dblAnnualRate As Double = dblNew_Rate

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click


        Dim dblVehicleCost As Double
        Dim dblDownPayment As Double
        Dim dblMonths As Double
        Dim dblLoan As Double
        Dim dblMonthlyPayment As Double
        Dim dblInterest As Double
        Dim dblPrincipal As Double
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim strOut As String
        Dim blnInputOK As Boolean = True



        If blnInputOK = True Then
            dblLoan = dblVehicleCost - dblDownPayment
            dblMonthlyPayment = Pmt(dblAnnualRate / dblMonths_Year, dblMonths, -dblLoan)
            lstOutput.Items.Clear()

            For intCount = 1 To dblMonths
                dblInterest = IPmt(dblAnnualRate / dblMonths_Year, intCount, dblMonths, -dblLoan)
                dblPrincipal = PPmt(dblAnnualRate / dblMonths_Year, intCount, dblMonths, -dblLoan)
                strOut = "Month" & intCount.ToString("d2")
                strOut &= ": payment =" & dblMonthlyPayment.ToString("n2")
                strOut &= ", interest =" & dblInterest.ToString("n2")
                strOut &= ", principal =" & dblPrincipal.ToString("n2")
                lstOutput.Items.Add(strOut)

            Next

        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        radNew.Checked = True
        dblAnnualRate = dblNew_Rate
        lblAnualRate.Text = dblNew_Rate.ToString("p")
        txtCost.Clear()
        txtDownPayment.Clear()
        txtMonths.Clear()
        lstOutput.Items.Clear()
        txtCost.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub radNew_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radNew.CheckedChanged
        If radNew.Checked = True Then
            dblAnnualRate = dblNew_Rate
            lblAnualRate.Text = dblNew_Rate.ToString("p")
            lstOutput.Items.Clear()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub radUsed_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radUsed.CheckedChanged
        If radUsed.Checked = True Then
            dblAnnualRate = dblUsed_Rate
            lblAnualRate.Text = dblUsed_Rate.ToString("p")
            lstOutput.Items.Clear()

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which line of the code throw the exception? I cannot find 'NPer' in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the variables from the input fields, preferably making sure that the user has input sensible values, for example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Const MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12
    Const NEW_RATE = 0.05
    Const USED_RATE = 0.08
    Dim annualInterestRate As Double = NEW_RATE

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Dim vehicleCost = 0.0D
        Dim downPayment = 0.0D
        Dim monthsToPay = 0

        Dim inputOk = Decimal.TryParse(tbCost.Text, vehicleCost) AndAlso
                      Decimal.TryParse(tbDownPayment.Text, downPayment) AndAlso
                      Integer.TryParse(tbMonthsToPay.Text, monthsToPay)

        If inputOk Then
            lstOutput.Items.Clear()

            Dim loanAmount = vehicleCost - downPayment
            Dim monthlyPayment = Pmt(annualInterestRate / MONTHS_PER_YEAR, monthsToPay, -loanAmount)

            For monthNumber = 1 To monthsToPay
                Dim interestPayment = IPmt(annualInterestRate / MONTHS_PER_YEAR, monthNumber, monthsToPay, -loanAmount)
                Dim principalPayment = PPmt(annualInterestRate / MONTHS_PER_YEAR, monthNumber, monthsToPay, -loanAmount)
                Dim strOut = $"Month {monthNumber:D2}"
                strOut &= $": payment = {monthlyPayment:C2}"
                strOut &= $", interest = {interestPayment:C2}"
                strOut &= $", principal = {principalPayment:C2}"
                lstOutput.Items.Add(strOut)

            Next

        End If

    End Sub

    ' other code here

End Class
```

It is convention to use UPPER_SNAKE_CASE for constants. Variables should (usually) be declared at the point of use.

In VB.NET, set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) and Option Infer On for an easier programming experience.

The `D` is a [forced literal type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters#literal-type-characters) for a Decimal value. The Decimal type should be used for money, even though the Pmt, IPmt, and PPmt functions don't (I suspect the Decimal type wasn't available when those functions were written).

I used [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) to show you how they could be used in your program: they can be useful for making code more readable.

[image: Sample output]